# Stream audio from a lm393 sound sensor with microphone raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, audio-streaming

I'm trying to implement a baby monitor using a raspberry pi with a lm393 sound sensor + microphone, like this one, http://www.dx.com/p/lm393-sound-detection-sensor-module-black-221267#.WEP3oaLhCRs.

I want stream the audio it receives when the sensor detects a louder noise.

What Im wondering is how to use the microphone to stream the audio, haven't found any info on this.

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. Because lm393 can only be used as a sound sensor, it needs an amplifier in order to be able to stream sound.